# Can someone explain why using OpenMP sections run slower than a single thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am new for the parallel programming.
According to the example code, Can someone explain why using OpenMP sections run slower than a single thread? and Is there any suggestion to improve it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <numeric>
#include<omp.h>

using namespace std;

int Calculation_1(int A, int B);
int Calculation_2(int A, int B);
int Calculation_3(int A, int B);
int Calculation_4(int A, int B);

int main() {

vector<int>W;
vector<int>X;
vector<int>Y;
vector<int>Z;

chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    #pragma omp sections nowait
        {
        #pragma omp section
            {
                W.push_back(Calculation_1(5, 5));
            }
        #pragma omp section
            {
                X.push_back(Calculation_2(5, 5));
            }
        #pragma omp section
            {
                Y.push_back(Calculation_3(5, 5));
            }
        #pragma omp section
            {
                Z.push_back(Calculation_4(5, 5));
            }
        }
    }

cout << "Parallel = " << accumulate(W.begin(), W.end(), 0) + accumulate(X.begin(), X.end(), 0) + accumulate(Y.begin(), Y.end(), 0) + accumulate(Z.begin(), Z.end(), 0) << endl;;
chrono::steady_clock::time_point end1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end1 - begin1).count() << std::endl;
//Clear vector
W.clear();
X.clear();
Y.clear();
Z.clear();

////Sigle
chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    W.push_back(Calculation_1(5, 5));
    X.push_back(Calculation_2(5, 5));
    Y.push_back(Calculation_3(5, 5));
    Z.push_back(Calculation_4(5, 5));

cout << "single = " << accumulate(W.begin(), W.end(), 0) + accumulate(X.begin(), X.end(), 0) + accumulate(Y.begin(), Y.end(), 0) + accumulate(Z.begin(), Z.end(), 0) << endl;
chrono::steady_clock::time_point end2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end2 - begin2).count() << std::endl;

cin.get();

return 0;

}

int Calculation_1(int A, int B) {
    return A + B;
}
int Calculation_2(int A, int B) {
    return A + B;
}
int Calculation_3(int A, int B) {
    return A + B;
}
int Calculation_4(int A, int B) {
    return A + B;
}
```

The results are:
Parallel = 40
Time = 9168172

Single = 40
Time 225580

The parallel one is 40 times slower than single one.

//I also have tried to push many numbers into the vector based on the suggestion (code below). The results are: (The parallel one is 9 times slower than single one.).

Parallel
Time = 12907862

Single
Time = 1334519

```
chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    omp_set_num_threads(2);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    #pragma omp sections nowait
        {
        #pragma omp section
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                    X.push_back(i);
                }
            }
        #pragma omp section
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
                    Y.push_back(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

cout << "Parallel = " << accumulate(X.begin(), X.end(), 0) + accumulate(Y.begin(), Y.end(), 0) << endl;;
chrono::steady_clock::time_point end1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end1 - begin1).count() << std::endl;
//Clear vector
X.clear();
Y.clear();

////Sigle
chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    X.push_back(i);
}
for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
    Y.push_back(j);
}


cout << "single = " << accumulate(X.begin(), X.end(), 0) + accumulate(Y.begin(), Y.end(), 0) << endl;
chrono::steady_clock::time_point end2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end2 - begin2).count() << std::endl;
```

Thank You very much,

Comment: How many cores do you have available at your target environment? Throwing stuff at threads, doesn't make them magically faster unless you have distinct CPU cores available to handle them.

Comment: Spinning up threads has a cost. What you are seeing is that cost.  Try adding loops to add many items into the vectors and see how that performs instead of adding a single item (which is a waste of a thread)

Comment: @Nathan That should be probably an answer. Let's wait a bit if the OP clarifies more about their target.

Comment: Make your calculation do much more than just a single addition that is likely optimized out anyways. The cost of creating threads is way more than the operation you are doing in the threads.

Answer (score 1):

Also notice that for such simple computations, the time ***cost of spamming the threads*** could be even greater that just compute them in a single thread.
Also as user0042 said, if you ***spam more threads than cores*** has your computer they will start scheduling the resources (cores) and sharing them, entering and exiting wich also slows down the computation.

Answer (score 0):

To *really* compute things in parallel (running threads independent of each other), you need to have dedicated CPU cores associated with your threads.

If you have more threads than CPU cores available, you'll just introduce overhead regarding thread creation and scheduling. That's most probably why your code slows down.

Comment: You could add some Parallel Efficiency graphs to demonstrate.

Comment: @Mel Well, no :-D. Feel free to do so yourself (edit my answer or post your own).

Comment: Haha maybe tomorrow! :)